# Programmatically Adding UINavigationBar and Status Bar

Tags: ios, storyboard

I'm creating a UINavigationBar programmatically and I want it to extend under the status bar. Here is the code:

```
_baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];[_baseView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
self.view = _baseView;
        
_navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];
        
[_navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[_navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
             
UINavigationItem* navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title!"];
[_navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes];
[_navigationBar pushNavigationItem:navigationItem animated:NO];
        
[_navigationBar setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
        
[self.view addSubview:_navigationBar];
        
[_navigationBar.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
[_navigationBar.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
[_navigationBar.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.topAnchor].active = YES;
[_navigationBar.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:64].active = YES;
```

Unfortunately the output is not quite right. As you can see in the image below the entire UINavigationBar is the correct size, purple, but the title and the rest of it is not the same size.

What am I missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is embed in a UINavigationController as azamsharp pointed out.

Another way is as follows.

Make your ViewController a UINavigationBarDelegate, set self as delegate when creating the UINavigationBar and then implement - (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:

Sample:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _baseView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
    [_baseView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    self.view = _baseView;

    _navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];

    [_navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [_navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];

    [_navigationBar setDelegate:self];

    UINavigationItem* navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title!"];
    [_navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes];
    [_navigationBar pushNavigationItem:navigationItem animated:NO];

    [_navigationBar setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

    [self.view addSubview:_navigationBar];

    [_navigationBar.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.leadingAnchor].active = YES;
    [_navigationBar.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.trailingAnchor].active = YES;
    if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
        [_navigationBar.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor].active = YES;
    } else {
        [_navigationBar.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor].active = YES;
    }
}

- (UIBarPosition)positionForBar:(id<UIBarPositioning>)bar {
    return UIBarPositionTopAttached;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a UINavigationViewController and push your UIViewController inside the UINavigationViewController as shown below:

```
let dishesTableViewController = DishesTableViewController()
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: dishesTableViewController)
```

Comment: I'd prefer to not use this approach if I can; although this is totally valid.

Comment: Why not use this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Tried this solution in Swift 4.1

```
let menuBar: UIView = {
    let mb = UIView()
    mb.backgroundColor = .red
    mb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return mb
}()

private func setupMenuBar(){
    view.addSubview(menuBar)

    let constraints = [ menuBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
                        menuBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
                        menuBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
                        menuBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)]
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
}
```